# Is there any command for force delete option in windows for folders similar to del /f filename for files rd /s /q is not working

Tags: windows

Is there any command for force delete option in windows for folders similar to del /f filename for files rd /s /q is not working as I need force delete option since multiple files in these folders are closed.

Answer (score 0):

Run `del` with the force option and recursion and `rd`afterwards. To check which parameters you need run `del /?` and `rd /?`.